# Datetime from a Datetime2 and Varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

For simplicity I have two columns in a table

```
DATE =  DateTime2(7)  2016-06-16 00:00:00.000000 
TIME =  Varchar(5)    09:00
```

I have tried several casts and conversions as shown below in the example to try and get them together into a new column as DateTime in **2016-06-16 09:00:00.000000** format:

```
convert(datetime, 
convert(varchar(10),DATE, 121) + ' ' + convert(varchar(8),TIME, 108)) 
as 'DateTime'
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How can a `varchar(5)` store 15 characters?

Comment: Apologies I'll edit that.

Comment: How is breaking what is (apparently) logically a single value into two separate columns "For simplicity". Surely it introduces more issues - firstly for recombining them (as here). Secondly, do you have a decent `CHECK` constraint on that time column? To ensure it doesn't contain `25:73` or `today`?

Comment: Thanks Damien.  I have no control over the data as its an external system that we have access to via SQL, hence the reason I need it in one column.  There's also a check on the data input to stop users entering the data in an incorrect format.

Answer (score 1):

Your `time` is already a string.  So you should be doing:

```
convert(varchar(10), [DATE], 121) + ' ' + [TIME]
```

If you only want HH:MM:SS format, use `LEFT()`:

```
convert(varchar(10), [DATE], 121) + ' ' + LEFT([TIME], 8)
```

This returns a string.

Do note that you can just add `datetime` values, so you might be able to do:

```
select [DATE] + CAST([TIME} as DATETIME)
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you Gordon.  The first is exactly what I need.  I tried similar variations but couldn't get it quite right.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DATE  DateTime2(7) =  '2016-06-16 00:00:00.000000' 
DECLARE @TIME Varchar(15) = '09:00:00.000000'

SELECT  CAST(
            CAST(@DATE as date) 
        as datetime) + 
        CAST(
            CAST(@TIME as time) 
        as datetime) As DateTimeValue
```

results:

```
DateTimeValue
-----------------------
2016-06-16 09:00:00.000
```